# Run a console app and close the window only if it succeeds

Tags: delphi, console, exit-code, createprocess, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to execute a console application from my GUI application and close the console window only if it is completed successfully. I tried this code, but when I call that function, a console window appears and disappears very quickly that I can't even see what's going on there... I tried to comment out everything after `CreateProcess`, but it still disappears. What am I doing wrong?

```
function RunDosApp(const AppName, Params, WorkDir: String): Boolean;
var
  SInfo: TStartupInfo;
  PInfo: TProcessInformation;
  CmdLine: String;
  Code: Cardinal;
begin
  FillChar(SInfo, SizeOf(SInfo), 0);
  SInfo.cb:= SizeOf(SInfo);
  SInfo.dwFlags:= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  SInfo.wShowWindow:= SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  CmdLine:= Params;
  if CreateProcess(PChar(AppName), PChar(CmdLine), nil, nil, True, 0, nil, PChar(WorkDir), SInfo, PInfo) then begin
   WaitForSingleObject(PInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
   GetExitCodeProcess(PInfo.hProcess, Code);
   if Code = 0 then begin
    CloseHandle(PInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(PInfo.hProcess);
   end;
  end
  else MainForm.Caption:= SysErrorMessage(GetLastError);
end;

RunDosApp('c:\windows\ffmpeg.exe', '-i "'+InFile+'" -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:40 -c copy "'+OutFile+'"', Folder);
```

Comment: "_completed_" implies the process ended. A process still living and its exit code are mutually exclusive. Why don't you execute `cmd.exe /K /S w:\hatever.exe -i "file"...`?

Comment: @AmigoJack If I use the "/S" parameter, I get "'/S' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."... Without "/S" it works, but then how can I read the console app exit code and close the widow if it is terminated succsesfully ?

Comment: Your function `RunDosApp` is not able to run an actual MS-DOS application. Consider naming it `RunCliApp` or something similar.

Comment: I bet large portions of the code including its function name are [copied from ancient code](https://www.google.com/search?q=RunDosApp) - not even the function's result is set anywhere.

Comment: It's only a test piece of code... It's not the final version. I didn't care about the name or the result at this point... :)

Comment: This code is leaking the process/thread handles if the exit code is not 0. You need to close the handles regardless of the exit code. The handles have nothing to do with the console window itself. I would suggest creating your own GUI window, and then [redirect the process's stdout/stderr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) to a pipe that you read from and display in that window as needed. Then you can do whatever you want with that window.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
Cmd1:= '@echo off';
Cmd2:= '...'; // your console app and its parameters here
Cmd3:= 'if errorlevel 1 pause';
ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'cmd', PChar('/c "'+Cmd1+'&'+Cmd2+'&'+Cmd3+'"'), PChar(Folder), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: This isn't flexible enough: anything but `0` must be considered a failure, [not only `1`](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob_plain;f=fftools/ffmpeg.c;hb=HEAD).

Comment: @AmigoJack That's what I thought the first time, but `errorlevel 1` means "greater than or equal to 1". See this: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/erroleve.htm

Comment: Thanks, I prefer to just execute `IF /?` instead of reading arbitrary websites tho.